# Insulate the frame of a door to stop odor outside while closed

Tags: doors, smell

This is an old wooden door and I am trying to keep the smell outside of it, I share the house with other people who fry very often.

I am thinking to get some foam strips for the frame and something to cover the bottom. This is the part I am more concerned about, I looked on the web but most hints I found are just to stop the cold outside.

Suggestions?

Comment: Your question is not quite so clear. Are you trying to keep odors inside the room or building? What kind of odors are you talking about here? Normally it is best to get rid of odors and disperse them to the outside.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelKaras, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stopping the cold from coming in is a matter of stopping outside air from getting in.  Stopping air flow will also prevent odors from coming in, so most of the guides you see for "weatherproofing" will apply to odor reduction.

Note that a strong odor is much more noticeable than a little bit of cold air, so when following the guides, be as precise and thorough as possible to stop as much air as you can.

Comment: The keyword to search for is "air sealing". Note that the door is only one place to look for air leaks.

Comment: Thanks @JPhil1618, I will try following some guides. Do you have any suggestions for the bottom of the door?

Comment: Adjustable door bottoms with multiple fins like [this one](www.lowes.com/pd_44205-1410-W79/36_0__?k_clickID=22986c4b-0e8d-47f8-ae9e-1a4ce672d6af&store_code=715&productId=3847231) should work well since each fin gives another chance to block air.